# Octopress blog - atom.xml generation - Entity 'ldquo' not defined

Tags: jekyll, blogs, octopress

I am trying to re-setup an existing Octopress blog to a new PC.

And When I generate pages.
An atom.xml is generated with following content at the first line.

And when I hit the browser I get an error:

```
This page contains the following errors: error on line 1 at column 28:
Entity 'ldquo' not defined Below is a rendering of the page up to the
first error.
```

My _config.yml file has this:

```
 subscribe_rss: /atom.xml
 subscribe_email:
 root: /
 permalink: /blog/:year-:month-:day/:title/
 source: source
 destination: public    
 plugins: plugins
 code_dir: downloads/code
 category_dir: blog/categories
 markdown: rdiscount
 rdiscount:
   extensions:
     - autolink
     - footnotes
     - smart
 highlighter: pygments
```

I think I am aware that ' chars are changed to ldquo due to rdiscount smart extension. But If thats the case, I should not be getting the error on browser.
I am confused. Any help would be great.

If I remove 'smart' extension, then the generated atom.xml does not contain the > , due to which it fails again and throws some other error.

Please help

Also raised here:
https://github.com/imathis/octopress/issues/1759

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its your config file.
Try to change the markup engine and see if its still displaying the error.

As i see it the  engine replace them and since i cannot see your code its hard to find out the exact problem.

Replace the markdown configuration and test it again.